# PHP Always Replace Apostrophe With Back-Slash Apostrophe

Tags: php

I have this simple PHP variable :

```
$Title = $_POST['text'];
```

and when it has this input : `here's the text`

the PHP will recognize as this when it written to a file : `here\'s the text`

```
$Filename = 'index.php';
$Handle = fopen($Filename, "r");
$Contents = fread($Handle, filesize($Filename));
fclose($Handle);

$TitleTag = extractor($Contents, "<title>", "</title>");

$Contents = str_replace ($TitleTag, $Title, $Contents); 
$Handle = fopen($Filename, 'w+');
fwrite($Handle, $Contents);
fclose($Handle);
```

how to get exactly just like what user typed? thanks

Comment: Check [`Disabling Magic Quotes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: @air4x: Lol, also check [migrating to 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.php), since magic quotes were removed from 5.4 all together

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I didn't get it from the question that the OP was using php 5.4. Also what else could explain PHP adding backslashes to single quotes in user inputs. That it has been removed from php 5.4 is given in a big red box in the Magic Quotes section itself.

Comment: @air4x: I voted your comment up, I completely agree: I don't think the OP is using 5.4 either, I just forgot about disabling magic quotes as a possible solution. For completeness I just wanted to add that magic quotes are removed from php in the latest release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and simple fix would be:

```
fwrite($handle,stripslashes($Contents));
```

[see the docs](http://www.php.net/stripslashes)
Alternatively, you could have php treat the contents as a string format, which will return the escaped characters correctly, too:

```
fwrite($Handle,sprintf($Contents));
```

But be weary, if there is a `%` char somewhere in your code, it'll have to be doubled, if not `sprintf` will treat it as a place-holder:

```
fwrite($Handle,sprintf(str_replace('%','%%',$Contents)));
```

This, then, requires two operations and is not the best approach, especially since I get the impression you're treating an HTML string (`style='width:50%'` <-- not entirely unlikely)